# Integrability of The Indicator of a Perfect Set

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-integration, cantor-set

I am having trouble solving the following problem:
Let $C$ denote the middle-third cantor set. i.e., $C = \bigcap_{i=1}^{\infty}C_n$ where
\begin{align*}
C_1 &= \left[0, \frac{1}{3}\right] \cup \left[\frac{2}{3}, 1\right] \\
C_2 &= \left[0, \frac{1}{9}\right] \cup \left[\frac{2}{9}, \frac{1}{3}\right] \cup \left[\frac{2}{3}, \frac{7}{9}\right] \cup \left[\frac{8}{9}, 1 \right] \\
& \vdots \\
C_n &= \bigcup_{(i_1,\dotsc,i_n) \in \{0,2\}^n} \left[ \frac{i_1}{3^1}+ \dotsc+ \frac{i_n}{3^n}, \frac{i_1}{3^1}+\dotsc + \frac{i_n+1}{3^n}\right] \\
& \vdots 
\end{align*}
Let $f$ be defined by
\begin{align*}
f(x) = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if $x \in C$} \\ 0 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}
\end{align*}
How can I show that $f$ is Riemann integrable (i.e., $f \in \mathcal{R}$) on $[0,1]$, and what would be the value of
\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{1} f(x) dx
\end{align*}

Comment: Are you familiar with Lebesgue's characterisation of Riemann integrability? I.e. a function $f$ is Riemann integrable iff its set of discontinuities has Lebesgue measure zero.

Comment: We haven't gotten yet to Lebesque theory in my class. We are using Rudin by the way

Answer (score 0):

Does the following answer look alright?
Let $\epsilon > 0.$ We want to show that there exists a partition $P$ of $[0,1]$ such that
\begin{align*}
U(P,f) - L(P,f) < \epsilon
\end{align*}
where $U,L$ denote the upper and lower sums. We choose $P$ to be such that
\begin{align*}
\Delta x_i &= \frac{1}{n}
\end{align*}
for all $i \in [n]$. Let $M_i(f), m_i(f)$ denote the supremum and infimum of $f$ respectively on interval $[x_{i-1}, x_i].$ Thus, we observe that
\begin{align*}
U(P,f) - L(P,f) &= \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} M_i(f) - m_i(f) \\
&\leq \frac{1}{n}
\end{align*}
We can choose $n$ to be arbitrarily large so that
\begin{align*}
U(P,f) - L(P,f) < \epsilon
\end{align*}